# How to change the order of grouped bar chart in dimple?

Tags: d3.js, graph, dimple.js

I have a data like this,

```
income  correlation bath_math_count bath_read_count
High    Negative    3   2
High    Not significant 7   12
High    Positive    17  13
Medium  Negative    0   0
Medium  Not significant 2   3
Medium  Positive    9   8
Low Negative    0   1
Low Not significant 6   8
Low Positive    19  16
```

My dimple code reads,

```
var svg = dimple.newSvg("#chartContainer", 590, 400);
d3.tsv("generated_data/test.tsv", function (data) {
  var myChart = new dimple.chart(svg, data);
  myChart.setBounds(60, 30, 510, 330);
  myChart.addCategoryAxis("x", ["correlation", "income"]);
  myChart.addMeasureAxis("y", "bath_read_count");
  var s = myChart.addSeries("income", dimple.plot.bar);
  // s.addOrderRule(["Low", "Medium", "High"]);
  myChart.addLegend(65, 10, 510, 20, "right");
```

It looks like
[image]

I'd like each group is arranged from "Low" to "High". If I uncomment the line commented above, the order of legends is changed but not the bars.
[image]
How to fix it?

Comment: I find the solution. Sorry to ask it in haste. I didn't intend to.

Answer (score 2):

OK... I soon find the addGroupOrderRule function here. 
http://dimplejs.org/examples_viewer.html?id=lines_horizontal_grouped_stacked

```
  var x = myChart.addCategoryAxis("x", ["correlation", "income"]);
  x.addGroupOrderRule(["Low", "Medium", "High"]);
```

These get the work done.